# how to get intent data one by one until last data

Tags: android, android-intent

i used an intent to get multiple images from gallery  using this code

```
public void image (View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("image/*");
    //i.setType("video/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(i, "android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"), 1);

}
```

now how to get images stored in this intent one by one until last image ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onActivityResult() try Intent Chooser.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<Uri> imageUris = ImageChooserMaker.getPickMultipleImageResultUris(this, data);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < imageUris.size() ; i++){
             Uri uri = imageUris.get(i);
            //Do your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to app gradle file into dependency tag:

```
compile 'com.tuanchauict.intentchooser:intentchooser:0.1.+'
```

Comment: just red line with cannot resolve symbol ImageChooserMaker

Comment: are you in an activity or fragment ?

Comment: i have copied your answer and paste it but still it says cannot resolve symbol ImageChooserMaker

Comment: Did you sync gradle and then run your app ?